# Android Google Plus Login - An internal error occurred

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm trying login my app with Google Plus.

My IDE is Android Studio.

For that I found this tutorial https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started

I'm with Android Studio 1.0 RC2

I did everything the tutorial sent, I'll post here my activity.

https://gist.github.com/b6e3c915094ba9ccca7d

The application opens and begins to initialize the login option via Google Plus.

But in one point he stop and to appear the error "An internal error occurred"

In my Android Studio got to go to the Build-> Generate Sign APK created a debug JKS.

I went to File-> Project Structure then on the "Signing" created the "config" pointing to my JKS, then went on the "Build Types" and "release" and "debug" put the "Signing Config" as "config" .

I was in my Google API Console, in my "API" activated the Google+ API and then "Credentials" and added a new "Client ID" with the SHA1 in my JKS.

In my AndroidManifest.xml now also has the

```
<meta-data
             android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
             android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I try to open the application and see ALWAYS "An internal error occurred".

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

This is my logcat:

```
12-16 15:55:42.877    2040-2040/com.domain.app D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
12-16 15:55:43.607    2040-2040/com.domain.app I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018_msm8610_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
    Build Date: 03/07/14 Fri
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.1
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018 + f2fd134 +  NOTHING
12-16 15:55:43.699    2040-2040/com.domain.app D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: Update question with my logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason I had this error was that I needed to implement the Public API access key in the Google console. The most important pieces of info here is the SHA1 number this tutorial worked for me on windows http://livingcode.co/index.php/2014/04/10/android-studio-how-to-get-debug-signing-certificate-on-windows/ and the app identifier eg com.example.app. I still had the error after that until I figured out I needed to implement the OAuth key too, have you done that?